# Chilkat - SFTP - Authentication failed or partial success

Tags: chilkat

Using Chilkat SFTP.  I can connect and but get  **Authentication failed or partial success.**
Any ideas?  thx in advance

Here's my code:

Chilkat.SFtp sftp = new Chilkat.SFtp();

```
    sftp.VerboseLogging = true;

    bool unlocked = sftp.UnlockComponent("Hello World");

    if (!unlocked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sftp.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }

    // Load a .ppk PuTTY private key"
    Chilkat.SshKey puttyKey = new Chilkat.SshKey();

    string key = @"C:\Key.ppk";

    string ppkText = puttyKey.LoadText(key);

    puttyKey.Password = "PassW0r@##(";
    bool success = puttyKey.FromPuttyPrivateKey(ppkText);
    if (success != true)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(puttyKey.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }

    string sshHostname = "sftp.XXXX.com";
    int sshPort = 2222;

    // Connect to an SSH/SFTP server
    success = sftp.Connect(sshHostname, sshPort);
    if (success != true)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(sftp.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }

    success = sftp.AuthenticatePk("USER1", puttyKey);
    if (success != true)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(sftp.LastErrorText);

       return;
    }

    success = sftp.InitializeSftp();
    if (success != true)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(sftp.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }
```

Here's the Error:

```
ChilkatLog:
  AuthenticatePk(4079ms):
    DllDate: Dec 27 2016
    ChilkatVersion: 9.5.0.65
    UnlockPrefix: Hello World
    Architecture: Little Endian; 64-bit
    Language: .NET 4.6 / x64
    VerboseLogging: 1
    login: XCA_HBECKI_EXTXCA_SFT001
    sshAuthenticatePk(4079ms):
      requestUserAuthService(32ms):
        sendServiceRequest:
          svcName: ssh-userauth
          SentServiceReq: ssh-userauth
        --sendServiceRequest
        ssh-userauth service accepted.
      --requestUserAuthService
      Using an RSA key.
      publicKeyBlobSize: 277
      msgPayloadSize: 353
      Sent public-key request.
      AuthList: publickey
      padAndSignHash(16ms):
        keyType: Private
        hashInSize: 20
        padding: PKCS v1.5
        HashOid: 1.3.14.3.2.26
      --padAndSignHash
      rsaSigLen: 256
      Sent public-key request with signature.
      Authentication failed or partial success. (4)
      PartialSuccess4: 0
      AuthList: publickey
      Publickey authentication failed..
    --sshAuthenticatePk
    Failed.
  --AuthenticatePk
--ChilkatLog
```

Answer (score 1):

It probably means the server requires both the private key and a password.  You would want to call AuthenticatePwPk instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to connect SFTP server with username and keyfile installed in Windows 10 server. I was getting same stacktrace and upgrading to chilkat-9.5.0-jdk11-x64.zip worked for me.